# HIVE table's Parquet data with special characters like 'á' 'è' '月' showing �

Tags: hive, character-encoding, parquet

We have a Hive table that has snappy.parquet data in the background as that table's data. The data has special european and asian characters  like 'á'  'è'  '月' . The Hive table has been loaded by converting an ASCII file to Parquet with SPARK save feature.The tables schema is as below

COL-NAME      STRING

---

**refnbr**         bigint
**man**            string
**spras**          string
**aatkg**          string
**wgbez**          string   [*Special Characters are in this field*]

**errez60**        string   [*Special Characters are in this field*]
**coller**         string
**t_id**           bigint
**filetag**        string.

---

On trying to do a normal select on this table it is showing the results but for the special characters it is showing something like this --> "**Carte de t�l�phone** ". However rest of the same field's data which doesn't have these special characters are showing up rightly.
Please advise if 
i) we need to set any Encoding setting at the HIVE table level and how would that be ? Or 
ii) Is it something to do with setting the serde properties with correct table-properties for encoding. What is that and how to do that. Would appreciate if you can please advise.
iii) OR if any other elements I may have missed on in here.

Comment: Please find below the create table statement that has been used to create the table. The tablename details are masked for confidential reasons.

Answer (score 0):

please try with simple text format (without parquet ) . with file saved with  UTF-8 characters.use this file to load table. Is Parquet format really needed ?

Comment: Yes Parquet format needed to optimize querying HIVE in our use case.

Comment: Hi @BigggDataaa I m able to fetch data as it is using parquet format . which verison of hive you are using? I m using Hive 1.1.0-cdh5.10.1